# Logstash - Use current date as timestamp date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I would like to use the current day as timestamp (date) as this information isn't available in our logfiles.
Example -> main_core.log:

```
04:00:19.675 [ActiveMQ Task-9] INFO  a.b.c.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully reconnected to ssl://localhost:12345
```

And i would like to split it and use the current day as date and the timestamp out of the logfile.

Is that even possible?

Thanks and many regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a field with the part of the timestamp that is missing in your log and then concatenate with a variable that contains the hour and use it as your @timestamp field.

The filter below does something like this:

```
filter {
    grok {
        break_on_match => false
        match => ["message","%{TIME:hour} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"]
        tag_on_failure => [ "_grokparsefailure"]
        add_field => { "time" => "%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"}
        add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{time} %{hour}" }
    }
    date {
        target => "@timestamp"
        match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    }
}
```

First it will match your message with a grok pattern that will extract the hour and save it in a field name `hour`, and the rest will be saved in a field name `msg`, but you can parse the rest if you want.

Then it will add a field name `time` with the pattern YYYY-MM-dd, for example `2018-07-12`.

After that, it will create a field named `timestamp` the field `time` with the field `hour`, which will result in `2018-07-12 4:00:19.675`

The `date` filter is used to use your generated timestamp as the default timestamp field in elastic, which is `@timestamp`.

A logstash output for this filter is something like this:

```
{
 "@timestamp":"2018-07-12T04:00:19.675Z",
 "message":"04:00:19.675 [ActiveMQ Task-9] INFO a.b.c.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully reconnected to ssl://localhost:12345",
 "timestamp":"2018-07-12 04:00:19.675",
 "msg":"[ActiveMQ Task-9] INFO  a.b.c.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully reconnected to ssl://localhost:12345",
 "time":"2018-07-12",
 "@version":"1",
 "hour":"04:00:19.675",
 "host":"logstash-hostname"
}
```